# Can't access MongoDB oid with object schema in laravel eloquent

Tags: mongodb, laravel

in laravel, I insert data to MongoDB with

```
$insert = DB::connection('mongodb')->collection('order_t')->insertGetId($data);
```

$insert will be an object, but I can't access oid with

```
$insert->oid
```

but if I use

```
foreach($insert as $k => $v){
      echo $k;
}
```

will see the key 'oid' so I can get the key with $v.

why? Is there any other way to access it?

If I do

```
dd(insert)
```

I get this result:

[image]

Comment: how many oid was printed in `foreach`

Comment: only one oid was printed

Comment: can you use `dd($insert);` and show the screen shot

Comment: I updated in my question